# PFLogInViewController/Facebook not working

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, ios7, parse-platform, pfloginviewcontroller

Using a PFLogInViewController subclass in my app to allow users to login with Facebook, I have an issue.
While it works perfectly in some cases; in other cases it doesn’t.

After I give permissions to the user the “Loading…” spinning wheel comes up and stays there for ever.
And some times it works but the waiting time (with the spinning wheel) is a bit long.

Though I now have quite a bit of experience with Parse.com, this is the first time I try to integrate Facebook login, therefore I may well be doing something the wrong way.

Here is some of the code I use related to this:

In the AppDelegate.m I do:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
……
   [PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebook];
……
    return YES;
}
```

and:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    BOOL fbAppCallStatus = [FBAppCall handleOpenURL: url
                                sourceApplication: sourceApplication
                                      withSession: [PFFacebookUtils session]];

    return fbAppCallStatus;
}
```

In the CustomLogInViewController.m I do:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    if ([PFUser currentUser])  [self quitView];
}
```

Let me know if there seem to be an obvious mistake here.

Thanks for any tip.